# Tub only drains when toilet is flushed

Tags: toilet, bathtub, blockage

My tub usually sounds haunted when flushing. I cleaned it for hair. Now it only drains when the toilet is flushed. My toilet is vintage 1960s and is in need of replacement anyways but this is bizarre.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. So, when you open the tub drain, nothing happens until you flush the toilet? More details might help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I’ll be taking a shower and it won’t drain. The bathtub just fills up until I flush the toilet. I’m planning on replacing the toilet since it’s slow to flush. I just am afraid their is a bigger issue than an old toilet.

Comment: Could be the stack vent is blocked, which allows air to escape as water enters the drain; could be blockage being forced out of the way by the "toilet water"...